# Why do the following statements give different outputs in Java?

Tags: java, exponent

For some values of x (x is of type long),

```java
 x %= (1e9+7);
```

and

```java
 x %= 1_000_000_007;
```

give different answers. Any idea why that could be?

Also, is this underscore format (1_000_000_007) common across languages? Are there advantages to it, apart from enhanced readability?

Comment: The first value, `1e9+7`, is a `double`, and the second, `1_000_000_007`, is an `int`. What is the type of `x`?

Comment: x is of type long

Comment: Gotcha. What is the value of `x`, and what are the results of each of the two operations on `x`?

Comment: as you pointed out, I think the problem is because of double vs int. I dont have the value of `x` but  the value after mod is 862275785 if I use the double value and 862275791 if we use the int value.

Comment: we can probably build the value of x to be  n*(1e9 +7) +  862275791

Comment: It makes sense that a difference of `6` would be caused by floating point arithmetic. See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What about `1_000_000_007L`?

Comment: 1_000_000_007L gives the same result as 1_000_000_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `1e9` is a `double` literal, and not every `long` value can be exactly represented as a `double`, so there is a loss of precision due to an implicit conversion from `long` to `double`.

[According to the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), `x %= d` is equivalent to `x = (long) (x % d)` when `x` is a variable of type `long` and `d` is of type `double`. The remainder operation also performs [binary numeric prommotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) on the operands, which converts `x` to type `double`.

Since `double` is a double-precision [IEEE 754 floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), it has 53 bits of precision for the mantissa, which is insufficient to represent all 64 bits of precision a `long` value may require. Put another way, both `double` and `long` use 64 bits, but there are many `double` values which are not `long` values, therefore there must also be many `long` values which are not `double` values. So the implicit conversion from `long` to `double` can result in a loss of precision for values greater than 2<sup>53</sup> or less than -2<sup>53</sup>.

By the way, because of the remainder operation, the error due to loss of precision could be up to 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 itself. For the input value `9_223_372_036_563_603_804L` the error is `999_999_659`, for example.